# Scikit one-hot-encoding with very expensive cost function neural network deep learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

I have a client who want me to build a NN/DL app for selecting a model for a very expensive cost (minutes to hours of runtime). The cost function is a non linear regression model of a pretty big data set (1000's - 10'000's of records), quasi-Newton minimization.  The NN/DL would select the structure of the model (e.g.,1, 2,3, 4 5 ODEs)- no closed form solution to the ODEs, parameters estimated by quasi Newton minimization. Can one hot encoding and NN/DL (e.g., Pytorch) do this? Can it be parallelized?

thanks
Mark

Comment: Can you provide more detail here? What exactly is the NN doing here? Is it estimating the cost function (but computes faster thus saving time), or is it selecting from amongst possible ODE formulations to minimize something? Also, you use cost both to mean the runtime of an algorithm, and some other cost representing the goodness of a model. So it's kind of a confusing problem formulation right now

Comment: Derek - thanks for your feedback. The NN will select "features" for a model. In linear regression, this would be the X's, like in stepwise regression. For example x1, x4, x11 and x25 from a list of x's so y = b0+b1*x1+b2*x4+b3*x11+b4*x25.The cost function is the SS for this regression. But, we have a non linear regression problem. More like your suggestion that the NN selects from among ODE formulations. Cost is only the "goodness of fit" statistic, does not include the run time (but run time needs to be reasonable - < 2 weeks probably).